# How to create a dismissable banner component in Reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to make a banner component that will render on a state of a context using react's createContext. I have passed the state and setState to the context , will allows the user to change the context state. I am storing this context state in localStorage which allows the context to presist after the website is closed.

but my context keeps rerendering non-stop.
This is my bannerContext code...

```
import React, { useState, useContext, createContext, useEffect } from "react";

const BannerContext = createContext({});

export const BannerProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [banner, setbanner] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
      setbanner(() => {
        const bannerState = window.localStorage.getItem("bannerState");
        return bannerState !== null ? JSON.parse(bannerState) : true;
      });
      window.localStorage.setItem("bannerState", banner);
 
  }, [banner]);
  return (
    <BannerContext.Provider value={{ banner, setbanner }}>
      {children}
    </BannerContext.Provider>
  );
};

export const useBanner = () => useContext(BannerContext);
```

How do i avoid rerenders and still check if with the local storage.

Comment: Modifying state value in use effect is not a good idea. If not handled properly it will trigger re-render continuously

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Issue

The effect is updating a value that is in its dependency array, i.e. `banner`, so this code will render loop.

## Solution

I don't think the `setBanner` in the effect is necessary. If I understand your code's purpose you want some component to call `setBanner` from the context and you want this `useEffect` to persist the new `banner` value to local storage.

1. Fetch the initial `banner` state from local storage when the component mounts. See [Lazy initial state](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#lazy-initial-state)
2. Use the `useEffect` hook to only persist `banner` state updates to local storage.

Code:

```
const BannerContext = createContext({});

export const BannerProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [banner, setBanner] = useState(() => {
    const bannerState = window.localStorage.getItem("bannerState");
    return bannerState !== null ? JSON.parse(bannerState) : true;
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    window.localStorage.setItem("bannerState", banner);
  }, [banner]);

  return (
    <BannerContext.Provider value={{ banner, setBanner }}>
      {children}
    </BannerContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

If the lazy initial state is giving you issues you can instead use a mounting `useEffect` hook to initialize state.

```
const BannerContext = createContext({});

export const BannerProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [banner, setBanner] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const bannerState = window.localStorage.getItem("bannerState");
    setBanner(bannerState !== null ? JSON.parse(bannerState) : true);
  }, []); // <-- no dependency, run once on mount

  useEffect(() => {
    window.localStorage.setItem("bannerState", banner);
  }, [banner]);

  return (
    <BannerContext.Provider value={{ banner, setBanner }}>
      {children}
    </BannerContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

Comment: I get your solution but window is not defined outside the useEffect. Is there any workaround solution for that?

Comment: Interesting. `window` is global in javascript, `window.localStorage` should be available just about anywhere in React code. You could move the entire `getInitialBannerState` to be an anonymous inline function in `setState`, i.e. `setState(() => { .... })`. You could also try removing `window` and just call `localStorage` directly.

Comment: async inline does not seem to work. Thanks for the response anyway

Comment: @Justin What async inline? There is no `async` declared code in your snippet nor my answer.

Comment: my bad. I read your suggestion wrong. I miss-read anonymous  for asynchronous .

Comment: @Justin Ah, no worries, it happens sometimes. I was poring over my answer to see if I had made a mistake. I did also update it to include an alternative method as well.

Comment: Thank you so much and sorry if I worried you.

Comment: @Justin Has my answer sufficiently resolved your issue or do you still have concern (or need time to test solution)?

Comment: @Justin Awesome! Good luck and cheers, mate.